# How to disable lock-Screen "Sign in Screen" when waking up from Hibernation in Windows 11?

Tags: windows, windows-11, lock-screen, start-screen, windows-11-preview

How to disable lock-Screen "Sign in Screen" when waking up from Hibernation Windows 11?
I tried every way on Google, but none of the methods works, I am asking when waking from Hibernation, It shows lock-Screen, where I have to Click Sign-in to continue, I don't want that, make sure ur answer works on your side Windows 11 in Hibernation mode.

Two common ways I tried:

- Group Policy Editor
- registry Edit

Comment: I understand your question. Lock Screen is built in. You need to put your request into Microsoft Feedback. I do this for features that bug me.

Comment: Ok I'll do it..

Comment: @John Did Microsoft remove that option since Windows 11? It is an option in Windows 10, but I don't like what they did to Windows 11, so I skipped it. Can't confirm if that works or not.

Comment: I do not see a way to remove the Lock Screen in Windows 11 (and the lock screen structure is worse in Windows 11 Insider so Microsoft is playing with it).

Comment: When you say you've tried everything, you need to list each and every thing you've tried. We need to know what you've tried so that we'll know what the issue is and what not to suggest. Please improve your question using the EDIT button. Also, we need to know whether this is a business computer or not.

Comment: Ok, I will mention.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into it myself and this helped me. Note, I don't have a password set for my account as it is the pc in my bedroom that I only use to watch videos upon.

I wanted Windows 11 to bypass any password, lock-screen, or sign-in, both at startup and when waking from sleep.  "Require Sign-In" was missing from sign-in options, so I had to trick Windows.  I am running Windows 11 Pro with a local account.  Here is what I did to fix the issues:

No Sign-In After Sleep:

1. From start menu, got to "Settings > Accounts > Sign-in options," and click "Password."
2. Click "Add" and create a password.  Note that once this step is complete, the hidden "Require Sign-in" option is revealed.  You may have to close and re-open "Settings" if it doesn't appear immediately.
3. From same menu, click "Require Sign-in" and click "Never."
4. Go back to "Password" and select "Change."  Do not enter a new password.  Leave all spaces blank and confirm your blank password.  This is equivalent to having no password.  You may notice that the "Require Sign-in" option is hidden again.  But do not fret, Windows remembers your "Never require sign-in" preference!  Now windows should open from sleep and take you straight to where you left off with no interruption.  This worked for me.